# Photo Gallery that thumbnails many, many photos

Tags: jquery, lightbox, image-gallery, photo-gallery

Can anyone recommend a jquery (or other) photo gallery that handles lots and lots of photos?

We have company events that generate maybe 250 photos. I'd like to put up a "wall" of thumbnails like MSN's "Wonderwall" but just the thumbnails- not all the crazy animation. Then viewers can go find themselves or co-workers in the thumbnails quickly and just click on (lightbox) the 15 or 20 photos they're interested in.

We're trying to avoid employees wading through 250 photos for an hour with a below-the-image slidebar gallery.

thanks,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi look at this http://trentacular.com/downloads/
at the galleriffic-2.0.zip (~135 KB) eks nr 2 i think 
and if you want to then you can connect fancy box to the gallery tumbnails..if not us it ass it are..

hope this works